# How to check jframe window opened .If jframe window opened than click outside then blinking jframe window in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Allow Only One Jframe window if try to open other than blinking jframe window in java swing **

HOW

**

Comment: Besides the two answers, see [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 2):

I can only guess what your question is supposed to mean, but my best guess would be that you want to create a **modal** frame. `JFrame` doesn't support this type of frame. You'll have to use `JDialog` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) instead.

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(parentFrame , "someTitle" , true);
... //create dialog

dialog.setVisible(true);
//now the parentFrame is blocked until the dialogwindow is closed
```

Comment: No that is not a dialog,This a  swing frame ,In java menu item at a time open one only How

Comment: That's a Dialog per definition. But i havent got the slightest clue what you want?

Answer (score 2):

> Allow Only One Jframe window if try to open other than blinking jframe
>   window in java swing

- don't to create more than one [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) to use [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) instead
- set [JFrame as owner for the JDialog with setModal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog-java.awt.Window-java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType-)

Comment: how to set jtextbox ,jtable and extra not suitable in jdialog